# VBA undo sorted records

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone please help me on the below scenario

I am able to sort the records using VBA on a particular cloumn ("M1") , now how to undo and keep the records in original position

```
Sub Sor_t()

  Dim oneRange As range 

  Dim aCell As range   

  Set oneRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RMData").UsedRange   

  Set aCell = range("M1")   

  oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance
Ram

Comment: Can you try `Sheets("RMData").ShowAllData`

Comment: copy paste the original data beforehand, then sort it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA clears the Undo buffer (can't undo the sorting)

However you can accomplish this with a workaround

- With the records unsorted create a new column (**hidden**), with sequential numbers
- Sort the records on any column, then revert to the initial sort using the  **hidden** column

--- Unsorted B column:

```
  Col A    Col B
    1        K
    2        Z
    3        A
```

--- Sorted B column:

```
  Col A    Col B
    3        A
    1        K
    2        Z
```

--- now sort by column A again

Answer (score 0):

1. you can copy the records to another column and then sort, so you keep the records on the original position; or,
2. you can asign a position number to your current records from 1 to n and then sort that column when you want to return to original...